# How to check if an element in arr1 exists in arr2 [BASH]?

Tags: bash, unix

arr1 contains elements "a" "b" "c"

arr2 contains element "b"

if elements of arr2 exist in arr1, then do....

How would I write this?

something along the lines of

```
for x in arr1
do
    if [ ${arr1[x]} == ${arr2[*]} ]
    then ...
    fi
done
```

?

Comment: haven't got the time, but use `comm -12 <(printf "%s\n" "${arr1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${arr2[@]}")`

Answer (score 0):

Checking values in arr2 present in arr1 :

```
arr1=("a" "b" "c")
arr2=("c" "d" "e")

for i in "${arr2[@]}" 
do 
  for j in "${arr1[@]}" 
  do 
  [[ "$i" == "$j" ]] && echo "$i" 
  done 
done
```

--> prints : c